# Problem: Consumer Driven Contract Testing with Pact

Tags: javascript, consumer, pact, contract

Im writing a small programm for a University project.
I'd like to test it with the pact framewok. Unfortunately, no Pact.json file is created for me, although there are no errors. My Consumer iss written in Javascript.
Below you can see the source code of my javascript file, the console output and my package.json file:

```
const {Pact} = require('@pact-foundation/pact');
const axios = require('axios');
const path = require('path');


describe('Pact Consumer', () => {
    const provider = new Pact({
        consumer: 'consumer',
        provider: 'producer',
        host:'127.0.0.1',
        port: 1234,
        log: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'logs', 'pact.log'),
        dir: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'pacts'),
        logLevel: 'INFO',
    });

    beforeAll(() => provider.setup());
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;
    describe('consumer', () => {

        beforeEach
        (() =>

            provider.addInteraction({
                state: "valid date",
                uponReceiving: "a request for JSON data",
                withRequest: {
                    method: "GET",
                    path: "/test",
                    headers: { Accept: "application/json" },
                },
                willRespondWith: {
                    status: 200,
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                    body:
                        {
                            name: 'Scherr',
                            surname: 'Valerian',
                            age: 28,
                        },

                },


            }),


        );

    });



    describe('test', () => {
        it('should return the correct data', () => {

          return  axios.get('localhost:1234/test').then(response => {
                expect(response[0].name).toBe('Scherr');
                expect(response[0].surname).toBe('Valerian');
                expect(response[0].age).toBe(28);
            }).then(()=> provider.verify())
        });
    });

    afterAll(() => {
        return provider.finalize();
    });
});
```

Console Output:

```
   Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 1234
Expected :
Actual   :
<Click to see difference>

error properties: Object({ errno: 'ENOTFOUND', code: 'ENOTFOUND', syscall: 'getaddrinfo', hostname: '1234', config: Object({ url: 'localhost:1234/test', method: 'get', headers: Object({ Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*', User-Agent: 'axios/0.19.2' }), transformRequest: [ Function ], transformResponse: [ Function ], timeout: 0, adapter: Function, xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN', xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN', maxContentLength: -1, validateStatus: Function, data: undefined }), request: Writable({ _writableState: WritableState({ objectMode: false, highWaterMark: 16384, finalCalled: false, needDrain: false, ending: false, ended: false, finished: false, destroyed: false, decodeStrings: true, defaultEncoding: 'utf8', length: 0, writing: false, corked: 0, sync: true, bufferProcessing: false, onwrite: Function, writecb: null, writelen: 0, afterWriteTickInfo: null, bufferedRequest: null, lastBufferedRequest: null, pendingcb: 0, prefinished: false, errorEmitted: false, emitClose: true, autoDestroy: false ...
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 1234
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:64:26)
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "webservice",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jasmine"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@pact-foundation/pact": "^9.11.0",
    "@pact-foundation/pact-node": "^10.9.5",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "jasmine": "^3.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "pact": "^4.3.2"
  }
}
```

I am grateful for any help and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell without logs here, but one things is for sure: your call to `axios.get` and `provider.verify` are promises and are not being correctly, meaning the execution of certain things will be out of order or will not actually execute at all.

Simply prefixing both with `return` should fix that issue.

See https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js#test-fails-when-it-should-pass.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick help. I'll get right on that.You mean the log file? 
It's right here: ````I, [2020-06-08T14:18:16.805906 #11736]  INFO -- : Verifying - interactions matched
I, [2020-06-08T14:18:16.818918 #11736]  INFO -- : Cleared interaction````

Comment: there are only two sentences

Comment: It looks like it thinks 1234 is the host, so something is wrong with your call using axios. Perhaps try http://localhost:1234 or read their docs about how to make the call

Comment: i have updatet my source code and console output above thanks in advance

Comment: yes i tried this before. But it doesnt work. i looked in the docs but there its the same. I think pact doesnt start the mock-provider

Comment: yes if i specify the adress with a baseUrl (http://localhost:1234) now i get a Request failed with status code 500 so this means the server isnt online right?

Comment: i also tried fetch instead of axios there is the same problem

Comment: Now it work when im using mocha instead of jasmine. Thank u for your help 

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Setting the `cors` property on the `provider config` to `true` did the job for me.

I didn't seem to have this problem when using `node-fetch` as opposed to `axios`.